# How do I get the http return code from an XHR object in mootools

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, mootools, xmlhttprequest

I am doing an AJAX request. In my `onFail` event of the `Request` I catch the `XHR` object.
What is the name of the member in this object that holds the code.
For that mater, I could not find a documentation that shows the list of members in that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just console.info `this` in the callback `onFailure` - `this.status` contains the http error response. `this.xhr` contains more about the request and extended responses.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/NF2jz/365/

```
new Request({
    url: '/secho/html/',
    data: {
        html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>" + "<script type='text/javascript'>$('target').highlight();<\/script>",
        delay: 3
    },
    method: 'post',
    onFailure: function() {
        var error = "Error " + this.status;
        switch (this.status) {
            case 404:
                error = "Document not found (404)";
            break;
            case 301:
                error = "Object moved permanently (301 redirect)";
            break;
            case 302:
                error = "Object moved temporarliy (302 redirect)";
            break;
        }
        alert(error);
    }
}).send();
```